# Open air water tank vs closed air tank

Tags: pressure, water, fluid-statics, flow

Between open air water tank and closed loop water tank, which one is given more water pressure? Can anyone help me, both tank located high enough to get gravity flow. Which one give high pressure of water? Closed tank or open tank

Comment: Sounds like you have a specific application in mind. Maybe you could describe it--what is "closed loop water tank?" Of what larger system is it a part? A domestic water supply maybe? What is the "loop?" If you can't provide more information, then you probably won't get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

An open to atmosphere tank with gravity fed delivery will have about 1.47 PSI for each meter of depth from the water's surface to the water output excluding small atmospheric pressure differences at these two points. A tank that is closed to the atmosphere will have the same approximate  1.47 PSI per meter of depth plus or minus the positive or negative air pressure above the water's surface. In a sealed non collapsing tank, at a depth greater than about ten meters its depth pressure will become greater than the atmospheric pressure and the water will flow.